# HPE V1910 VLAN configuration

Tags: switch, vlan, hp

I have a HPE v1910 switch for my network. I am creating 5 VLANs on it for my purposes:

```
VLAN 11- ports 9/10, port 10 has a Linux box and port 9 is connected to an external device. 
VLAN 12- ports 11/12, port 12 has a Linux box and port 11 is connected to an external device.
VLAN 13- ports 13/14, port 14 has a Linux box and port 13 is connected to an external device.
VLAN 14- ports 15/16, port 16 has a Linux box and port 15 is connected to an external device.
VLAN 15- port 7 only which is also a Linux box
```

What I am trying to accomplish is creating a way for the PC on port 7 to be able to talk to only the PCs on ports 10/12/14/16. I don't want the packets to make it to the external devices as they act as bridges.

I have read through the user manual and didn't find it much help. Any help or insight into how I would accomplish this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you not want to use ACLs on the SVIs to filter the traffic? Like, put an ACL on the SVI for VLAN 15 that only permits it to reach the IP addresses for the PCs on ports 10, 12, 14, and 16, and deny everything else.

Comment: Have you set up routing? ACLs? What is the configuration and what from it doesn't work? Without details, your question cannot be answered, leading to speculation, making it off-topic here.